# How do I add an incrementing ID for each sentence in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I was able to replace the punctuation with span tags and separate the sentences, but I tried to increment the id by one for each sentence and it only worked on the first one.

```
$('.whatever').each(function(index) {
     var sentences = $(this).html().replace(/([^.!?]*[^.!?\s][.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g, 
     '<span id="'+index+'">$1</span>$2<SENTENCE_END>');
     $(this).html(sentences);
});
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your text is inside `#whatever`, you'll want to first split the text by periods and then iterate through each of those to add `<spans>`.

Here's an example:

```
// set counter
var j = 0;

// get text from div
var sentences = $('#whatever').text().trim();

// split text by "."
var sentences = sentences.split('.');

// empty the output div
$('#whatever').empty();

// for each sentence, check for blank sentence,
// add span with counter number, trim spaces,
// add leading space if this is not the first sentence,
// add "." at the end of sentence, output to div
$(sentences).each(function () {
    if (this.trim()!='') {
        $('#whatever').append( (j>0?" ":"") + '<span class="sentence" id="sentence_' + j + '">' + this.trim() + '.</span>');
        j++;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FrDzL/1/

Comment: This is great, but it works only for periods.  How about !s and ?s  I tried splitting on `/([^.!?]*[^.!?\s][.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g` , but that didn't seem to work.  Great direction though, thanks.

Comment: You should probably try to reduce the number of selections you make by saving the element in a jQuery object - `var $whatever = $('#whatever')`

Comment: I ended up doing it differently with match(), unshift() and push(), but thanks.  Best answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the id selector? The id selector `$('#whatever')` only selects one element (the first element matching the id on the page). Hence that each loop is only executed once (that's why it only worked in the first one).
Modify your html code to use classes, and select using $('.whatever').

> ID Selector (“#id”)
>
> Selects a single element with the given id attribute.
>
> Source: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: I just tried converting everything to class, but every sentence now just has class=0

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

HTML

```
<p class="whatever">hej</p>
<br>
<p class="whatever">hej</p>
<br>
<p class="whatever">hej</p>
```

JS

```
var j = 0;

$('.whatever').each(function() {
     var sentences = $(this).html().replace('hej','nej');
     j++;
     $(this).html(sentences);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PXNL/)

**And finally, working code for your example**

```
var j = 0;

$('.whatever').each(function() {
    var sentences = $(this).html().replace(/([^.!?]*[^.!?\s][.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g, 
 '<span class="sentence" id="'+j+'">$1</span>$2<SENTENCE_END>');
    j++;
    $(this).html(sentences);
});
```

Comment: No that made no difference.

Comment: Did not notice the selector was on id. You need to set a class.
Ill put a working fiddle up.